# Where are all the Barns located in Forza Horizon 2?

Tags: forza-horizon-2

There are 10 Barns again in the second installation of Forza Horizon.... Where are they all located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to find a [pretty detailed guide here](http://segmentnext.com/2014/09/30/forza-horizon-2-barn-finds-locations-storage-find-guide/), but just in case that link goes down:

**EDIT: Note - these barn finds may not be in order as I found #9 first, as did [Rapitor](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/47011/rapitor)**

> **Barn Find #1** – Lamborghini Miura P400
>   Location: To find this car, you need to travel to the Horizon Festival and travel to the south side of the ‘HF’ pink blimp on your mini-map. You need to travel along the dirt road with wooden barricades on the sides.
>
> Eventually, you will come across two buildings and a garage door in
>   the middle of these buildings. Stand in front of you to find the car.
>
> **Barn Find #2** – Ferrari 250 GT Berlinetta Lusso Location: This is a
>   pretty hard one to find, but if I can manage it, anyone can. To get
>   this car, you need to travel to the north side of Casteletto and
>   travel to the smaller circle showed in the image. You will find the
>   barn right next to some buildings near trees.

[image]

> **Barn Find #3** – Ford Capri RS3100
>   Location: You will find this car in the southeast side of Montellino. You will find a tractor parked inside a shed near the location of this garage. In addition to this, the area also contains an XP board.

[image]

> **Barn Find #4** – Volkswagen Type 2 De Lux
>   Location: This is another tough one to find. To find this, you need to travel to the north side of Montellino and stick to the west side of the dirt road near the area provided in the image. The garage will be located near some buildings enclosed by small stone walls.

[image]

> **Barn Find #5** – Jaguar XK 120 SE
>   Location: You need to travel to the upper side of the San Giovanni Car Meet icon on your mini-map to find this amazing car. Travel up the hill and get to the right side of the ‘P’ icon to find this rusty old car.

[image]

> **Barn Find #6** – Ferrari GTO
>   Location: In order to find this car, you need to travel to the small circle in the image and turn right from the intersection. You will come across a large dirt road on your left side with another small/hidden dirt road a little ahead.  You need to travel to the smaller dirt road on the left side and keep on following the path to find this car.

[image]

> **Barn Find #7** – Jeep WILLYS MB
>   Location: You need to travel to the designated location and you will come across a road with a small white stone border on one side. You need to find a gap in this border and go a little right from the entrance to find this car.

[image]

> **Barn Find #8** – Alfa Romeo Giulia TZ2
>   Location: Get to the area showed in the image and turn right from the intersection. Keep on going straight and you will come across large blue truck parked outside the barn find.

[image]

> **Barn Find #9** – Renault Alpine A1 10 1600S
>   Location: To get this car, you need to cross the river and get to purple fields. Do note that you need to stick to the purple side of the dirt road to find this barn.

[image]

> **Barn Find #10** – Maserati Tipo 61 Birdcage
>   Location: You need to get to the location shown in the image and go through the woods to find the lone barn up the hills.

[image]

*All credit to **Arslan Tufail** at the site listed above*

Comment: I don't think these are in any special order like you have listed, I got leads/found the Renault(#9) first, and then the Volkswagen Hippie Van(#4) second. Haven't gotten anymore leads.

Comment: Agreed.  I will throw a disclaimer in the post above as I found #9 first as well.

Comment: Can you "find" the cars without waiting for the calls about them? Meaning, could I just take a trip around the countryside and collect all 10, or do I have to wait for a phone call about each one before I can get that particular car?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen No, you have to "discover" the barn find as you play the game and gradually are told about them. You can't just start the game for the first time and immediately find them all.

Comment: I can't seem to find #8; I found the big dirt road on the left but never found a smaller one ahead of it. Does anyone know where barn find #6 is?

Answer (score 0):

Your barn find #8 is in a different place than what your post says it is, you can either go straight through the intersection and make a right at the collectable lightening sign or make the right and then make an immediate left on the dirt path. Also the truck is in fact a big blue tractor. But other than that your post was very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Please post this as a comment on the post you are referring to, not as a answer. Since you can't post comments yet, try exploring the site and answering/asking/editing some questions to get some reputation. After that, feel free to comment on that post.