# Free Cars in Forza Horizon 2

Tags: forza-horizon-2

On XBox One, my son plays Forza Horizon 2 and he's been finding free cars in the Auto Show.  I cannot find any!  How does the aspect of free cars work in Forza?

Comment: Does your son have DLC installed while you don't? I know if FH3 DLC cars can be obtained for free in the auto show, but I'm not sure about FH2.

Comment: I had asked him and he didn't think he did, unless he did and doesn't know it...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this are the barn finds. In FH2 there exist 10 cars that you can find on the country side and then are added for no costs.

Here you can find more information:
[Where are all the Barns located in Forza Horizon 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185682/where-are-all-the-barns-located-in-forza-horizon-2)

Sorry, but I can not comment yet. I will delete this answer if it does not help at all :)

Comment: These were definitely in the Auto Show; that link will most definitely be useful :-)